# Unity Keep getting: "Can not play a disabled audio source"

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, onmouseclick

I'm busy for a project for school wroking in unity with c#.
Now i have 2 objects the 'Master' object and the "Player" object.
When the master clicks on his mouse I want that a sound is spawned on the player object:

Script of the master involving sound looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class ClickControl : Photon.MonoBehaviour {
    public AudioClip newClip;
    public GameObject other;

    public void Click(){
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        Debug.Log (other.audio.enabled);

        other.audio.clip = newClip;
        other.audio.Play();}
    }

    public void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        Click ();       
    }
}
```

Of course there is more around it but that doesnt involve the sound.
The problem i get is when i insert an audioclip in the AudioClip and the Player in the GameObject i get this message: "Can not play a disabled audio source"

I tried with code to add a new audiosource to the GameObject and still this same message. I tried to instantiate it and still the same message. I'm out of options anyone a clue? 
This is my first question please excuse me for the lay out.

Answer (score 1):

you should add AudiSource to your other GameObject , try to do it before running the scene and if you want to add it in code add it in `Awake` because otherwise there is no audio source , also there is no need for the second `Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)`

```
 public void Click(){
        other.audio.clip = newClip;
        other.audio.Play();}
    }

    public void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        Click ();       
    }
```